# error in process filter: could not create connection to marmalade-repo.org:433

Tags: package

When I run `package-install` in windows with `Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) of 2015-04-11 on LEG570` I got error `error in process filter: could not create connection to marmalade-repo.org:433`

According to the [web site](https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/#windowsinstructions) of marmalade, that happens because they changed `http` to `https` and to avoid the error I followed the instruction.

But by `M-x package-refresh-contents` I got the same error `error in process filter: could not create connection to marmalade-repo.org:433`.
What can I do to avoid the error?

Comment: Are you running Eli's GnuTLS build of Emacs on Windows?

Comment: I don't know what is `Eli's GnuTLS build`, where can I check if I'm using it?

Comment: It's literally the first line of the "Installing with Windows" section you linked to. I'm not familiar with the Windows build myself but given it mentions it and GnuTLS is responsible for handling https it would seem on Windows having a build with GnuTLS enabled is important. You can test your current emacs with Meta-: (gnutls-available-p)